# PHP captcha not working

Tags: php, laravel, captcha

I'm using Laravel with this package https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha and for some reason It's not displaying the images. I checked if GD library is installed and enabled and it is. I've also tried this one https://github.com/igoshev/laravel-captcha and same thing happens. I cannot see image on the page and when I inspect the page I can see the URL to the image, but when I click it it's just black.

Comment: Try using Google ReCaptcha https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html and Laravel package https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha

Comment: @rsakhale  I can't use google's Captcha. If I could I would've used it already.

Comment: Any errors in laravel.log file?