# Laravel PHP Captcha Not Working (mewebstudio)

Tags: php, laravel, captcha

I've got exactly the same problem as posted in this question:
[PHP captcha not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232432/php-captcha-not-working)

That question is:

> I'm using Laravel with this package
>   https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha and for some reason It's not
>   displaying the images. I checked if GD library is installed and
>   enabled and it is. I've also tried this one
>   https://github.com/igoshev/laravel-captcha and same thing happens. I
>   cannot see image on the page and when I inspect the page I can see the
>   URL to the image, but when I click it it's just black.

At the moment I'm trying to get the mewebstudio captcha to work, but I've tried the igoshev one as well but it doesn't work either. Both do the same thing as described in the question above. Since the question didn't get an answer I figured I'd ask again. I'm running version 5.4.10 of the Laravel framework. It just displays a blank image with no errors. The strange thing is, it used to work and when I tried to use it again one day it started doing this since, even if I do a clean set up.

[Image of what the captcha looks like when it loads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rlbc.png)

Comment: Make sure your Ad blocker is off in your browser.

Comment: I've run it in browsers without Ad blocker extensions, it still doe the same thing.

Comment: Are you seeing any JS errors in the console of your browser? What about SSL? Is this on the localhost or live? Also, what do you see in the terminal when you load the page?

Comment: I'm not using any JS, it's just PHP. No SSL and it's running via localhost on Ubuntu. Which terminal are you referring to? I can't see any obvious errors when debugging in the browser. I can also access the image URL without problem but it only shows an empty/transparent image with nothing else. As if it is not being generated at all.

Comment: Running Laravel you need to use cmd with `php artisan serve`. If you refresh and something is wrong you should get a bad response or something.

Comment: Also, make sure the images are correctly linked. If the images are in the folder they should be. Check with firebug the path and check if you have the images uploaded there. I actually see it is made of a background and font. You should probably test it in the live environment.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes mewebe studio doesn't work properly. So you can use [zablos](https://github.com/zablose/captcha) captcha instead. zablose captcha is built based on mewebe studio. After installing the package via composer you can view the image like this:

```
<img src="{!! captcha_url('flat') !!}" alt="captcha" >
```

Read the docs at github page. also you can modify the captcha picture, color, fonts and symbles in
config: `vendor/zablose/captcha/config/config.php`

fonts: `vendor/zablose/captcha/assets/fonts`

symbles and colors: `vendor/zablose/captcha/src/Config.php`

sometimes the fonts and symbles of this captcha can be tricky. So make sure you modify it.